# eclipseFP2 haskell unix haveing issues connectiong to Scion Server

Tags: eclipse, haskell

I am having troubles with using FP2 for eclipse and getting it to connect with the server.

Eclipse seems to auto-detect scion_server, but I a error in the log file

```
!ENTRY net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.scion.client 4 4 2010-04-15 10:40:06.580
!MESSAGE The connection with the Scion server could not be established.
!STACK 0
The connection with the Scion server could not be established.
    at net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.scion.internal.client.ScionServer.connectToServer(ScionServer.java:328)
    at net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.scion.internal.client.ScionServer.startServer(ScionServer.java:73)
    at net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.scion.client.ScionInstance.start(ScionInstance.java:94)
    at net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.scion.client.ScionInstance.runCommandSync(ScionInstance.java:207)
    at net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.scion.internal.commands.ScionCommand.run(ScionCommand.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.scion.internal.client.ScionServer.connectToServer(ScionServer.java:345)
    at net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.scion.internal.client.ScionServer.connectToServer(ScionServer.java:324)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have just fixed one of these by getting telling elipsefp where to find scion:

```
window -> preferences -> Haskell -> scion
```

I thought I had it set up right but it may have been thrown by some changes to the system and PATH. Resetting scion configuration resolved the issue.

Of course you may be having an entirely different problem...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I *hadn't* fixed eclipseFP in the above answer.

This time I rebuilt Eclipse, unpacking eclipse-java-galileo-SR2-win32.zip and manually adding the folders from net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell_1.110.zip Just to be sure I discarded my workspace and started over (though I didn't clean out the source tree of the eclipse files).

That seemed to work. I have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: For future reference: please edit your original answer instead of posting a new one.